# How to parse result by Custom Search Engine

Tags: java, android, jsoup, google-search

I'm using Jsoup to parse data from a website. But I don't know how to parse search result by CSE (custom search engine).

Please review images below.

[Search Result](http://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2015/10/06/Untitledcfc32.png)

In search result, I want to get: image, title, link and description.

If you know, you can give me some solution!

Link Search:

> http://www.truyenngan.com.vn/tim-kiem.html?q=love&cx=000993172113723111222%3Auprumhk-rde&cof=FORID%3A11&ie=UTF-8&siteurl=www.truyenngan.com.vn%2F&ref=&ss=419j62441j4

`

Answer (score 0):

When you'll parse  page.asXml() you will get the source code which will definitely fetch the whole page data.
You need to apply some parsing logic,as the links will be with particular div/class/id ,so you can fetch them by looping.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(page.asXml());
Elements elements = doc.getElementsByTag('<id/div/class>');
```

Iterate elements to get value of all the links and description.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Custom Search Engines API, and you will be getting parsed results in JSON.